# VBA Word change font size of specific words in a table cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-2010

From Excel I am editing a Microsoft Word document. I have a table in my Word document where column 4 consists of a number and then the letters *wk* after it.

Example:

```
+------+------+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4  |
+------+------+------+-------+
| test |    2 |  123 | 1 wk  |
| test |    2 |  123 | 13 wk |
| test |    2 |  123 | 10 wk |
+------+------+------+-------+
```

I am trying to change the font size of the letters *wk*. I figured I could do this with selection and then replace the letters, but it's definitely not working in VBA via Excel. How can I achieve this?

My current code:

```
Tbl.Columns(4).Select
WDApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With WDApp.Selection.Find
    '.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "wk"
    .Replacement.Text = "wk"
    .Font.Size = 9
End With
WDApp.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is the table with your values in Excel or Word?

Comment: @TotsieMae The table is located in Word

Comment: You need to be changing `.Replacement.Text`’s size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested and on mobile, so bear with me here.

Currently you’re not changing the text size of the “replacement” text, so you should update to `.Replacement.Font.Size = 9`

```
With WDApp.ActiveDocument.Content.Find

    .ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions

    .Text = "wk"

    With .Replacement
        .Text = "wk"  'this line might be unnecessary
        .Font.Size = 9
    End With

    .Execute Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Tbl.Columns(4).Select
With WDApp.Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "wk"
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Font.Size = 9
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

**Note:** If the only cells containing 'wk' are in column 4, you don't need to select the column. For example:

```
With WDApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "wk"
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Font.Size = 9
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```